# $Sym^n(V\otimes U) = \oplus_{\rho \vdash n}V(\rho)\otimes U(\rho)$

Tags: representation-theory

As in the title, I would like to prove that, given vector spaces $V$ and $U$ that

$$Sym^n(V\otimes U) = \oplus_{\rho \vdash n}V(\rho)\otimes U(\rho)$$

Where $\rho \vdash n =\{(\rho_1,\rho_1,..,\rho_n) \in \mathbb{N}^n\vert\rho_1 \ge \rho_2 \ge ... \ge \rho_n \ge 0, \sum \rho_i=n \}$ (i.e. all partitions $\rho$ of $n$)

Where do I begin with such a decomposition? This breaks $Sym^n(V\otimes U)$ into $GL(V) \times GL(U)$ modules, but I don't see how its true.

This is part (b) of a two-part question. In (a) I showed all modules of the symmetric group of $n$ elements is self-dual; but I don't see how this applies.

Comment: What does $\rho \vdash n$ mean?

Comment: This is nothing by definition right?

Comment: I've edited the question. It means all partitions of $n$

Comment: And what do you mean by $V(\rho)$ and $U(\rho)$?